# save uiimage to photo library in ios extension

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, uiimage

```
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:[image CGImage] orientation:(ALAssetOrientation)[image imageOrientation] completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error){
    if (error) {
    // TODO: error handling
    } else {
    // TODO: success handling
    }
}];
```

I used above code to save `uiimage` to photo library in my custom keyboard extention.  But I've got access denied error.  I tried to allow this extension to access to photo library but I can not see this extension in the `Setting->Privacy->Photos`. Please help me!   Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Please read the [Understanding privacy and Location Services on iPhone, iPad, and iPod touch with iOS 8 document](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203033).

Apple says,

> You can turn Location Services on or off at Settings > Privacy >
>   Location Services. You can turn Location Services on either during the
>   Setup Assistant process or later through the Location Services
>   setting. You can individually control which apps and system services
>   have access to Location Services data. When Location Services are off,
>   apps can't use your location in the foreground or background. This
>   will limit the performance of various Apple and third-party apps.